# Starting a debugging session for Django in PyCharm

Tags: django, pycharm

In PyCharm, when developing a Django site, I can start the internal Django server by clicking the green `Run` arrow, but there seems to be no way to stop this server. If I ran it from a shell, I could would terminate it with CTRL+C, but I don't think I can do that in PyCharm.
If I press the `Run` button again, it says it can't run the server because the port is already being used (by the previous run that I couldn't terminate). Annoying, but usable.
The problem is that in this state it doesn't stop at breakpoints. In order to do that, I have to start the server with the `Debug` button, not the `Run`. But since it is already running, I can't start it for debugging!

So the question is, how do I stop the internal server that I started by using `Run` in PyCharm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a `Run` area (by default at the bottom left). If it is not visible, you have to press the mysterious square button at the absolute bottom left of your window.

[image]

Within the run area, there is another toolbar with which you can control the server. There is a stop button (Ctrl+F2) there.

Answer (score 1):

When the server is running, under the Run menu you have a Stop option that would stop the server. On Mac, the keyboard shortcut is Cmd-F2.

Answer (score 1):

Pycharm has two window modes - you are probably in mode with hidden toolbars, if you click on the screen icon in bottom left corner it will expand and show the plugins and there you will see Debug/Run windows with controls. Then simply click at the red 'stop' button and it will stop.